# C++ could not resolve method .open for fstream object

Tags: c++

I am having trouble using fstream in a very simple code here it is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
string line;
fstream file;

file.open("taches.txt", ios::in);


return 0;
}
```

Problem is Eclipse is giving Method 'open' could not be resolved but since I included fstreams and iostream I am baffle. Can soemone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If it could help I ma on linuxmint 16 using linux gcc

Comment: This works for me fine using gcc 4.7.4.  

EDIT: Okay, I can compile it either way.  I think your problem might be in Eclipse.  What version of gcc do you have?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code (it is actually C++11-compatible). Try fstream file ("taches.txt", ios::in); as workaround.

Comment: Not necessarily (and I'd assume probably not). In a terminal, type gcc --version and report the output.  That's a start at least.  Second would be the entire error output that you see in Eclipse.

Comment: gcc --version gives me 4.8.1 as for the entire Eclipse error thats about it.

Comment: Never mind I saved close/reopen Eclipse and the error is gone all is fine thank you every one.